# How do you prompt someone to continue their story?

Tags: translation

In English, sometimes you'd say things like 'I see', 'All right', 'Got it', 'Go on', etc., to show the other guy that you're still listening to what he's saying.

How do you say the equivalent in German? *Alles klar* or *Weiter* probably don't quite cut it here.

Comment: hm, hm, ja, hm, aja, aha, hm, ja, ja, ok, ja, hm, hm, ahhh, oh, aha, hm

Comment: @Em1 Really? Wow. My German boss used to interrupt me with a very loud *Hmm*, whenever we were speaking English. Up until now, I thought he was signaling me to shut up.

Comment: @Mihai: He could as well have been. Without knowing the intonation and your boss, it’s impossible to tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a bit more serious note than my comment above (which is true, though), you can go with the following ones.

Request to continue:

> OK, weiter.
>   Und weiter?
>   Und dann?

Express surprise(, and sometimes request approval):

> Echt?
>   Wirklich?

Express understanding:

> Verstehe.

Anyhow, there's a sheer endless list of variations, but these are the most common ones I guess.

The fillers *hm*, *ja*, *ok*, *ah* are used to merely show that you're still listening.

Comment: *Und daaannnn?* NO UND DANN! *Uunnnddd dddaaaannnnnnn?* NO UND DANN!!

Comment: @corsiKa Du hast zuviel "Ey Mann, wo ist mein Auto" geguckt. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Neutral:
ja, ok, (ich) verstehe, und dann? und weiter?

Approving:
natürlich, sicher, klar